# react component connected, redux state changes... but no update to component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a React/Redux front-end for a multi-channel chat app. I'm having problems getting some React components to re-render after state change while using `redux`, `react-redux`, and `redux-thunk`.

I believe that my reducers are non-mutating, and that I'm subscribed via `react-redux`'s `connect`. When I run the app and view the browser console, I see the initial render of the component (i.e. with initial, empty state), then the state change (triggered by an action dispatch in `index.js`)....  I would then expect the component to re-render with new props, but it doesn't happen.

[image: console log]

I've put up a repo here:
https://github.com/mattmoss/react-redux-no-update

`node_modules` is not in the repo, so to run, first download dependencies (running `yarn` is sufficient), then `npm start`.

Some excerpts (see full source in repo):

#### `reducers/channelList.js`

```
import * as c from '../actions/constants';

export default function channelList(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case c.FETCH_CHANNELS_SUCCESS:
            return action.channels;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

#### `actions/channelActions.js`

```
export function fetchChannels() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return ChannelApi.allChannels()
            .then(channels => dispatch(fetchChannelsSuccess(channels)))
            .catch(error => { throw(error); });
    };
}

export function fetchChannelsSuccess(channels) {
    return {
        type: c.FETCH_CHANNELS_SUCCESS,
        channels
    };
}
```

#### `components/ChannelListView.js`

```
class ChannelListView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { channels, current, onSelect } = this.props;

        console.log("channels:", channels, "current:", current);

        return (
            <ListGroup>
                {channels.map(channel =>
                    <ListGroupItem
                        key={channel.id}
                        active={channel.id === this.props.current}
                        onClick={onSelect(channel.id)}
                    >
                        <strong>#{channel.name}</strong>
                    </ListGroupItem>
                )}
            </ListGroup>
        );
    }
}

export default ChannelListView;
```

#### `containers/ChannelList.js`

```
import ChannelListView from '../components/ChannelListView';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        channels: state.channelList,
        current: state.currentChannel
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSelect: (id) => () => {}
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChannelListView);
```

#### `App.js`

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <h1>Channels</h1>
            <ChannelList />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

#### `index.js`

```
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(fetchChannels());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### `store/configureStore.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
    );
}
```

Comment: can you show `configureStore` as well?

Comment: @MichaelPeyper Edited to show `configureStore`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% as I am still relatively new to React myself. But look at your `index.js` script.

```
// You configure the store, then dispatch the fetchChannels action
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(fetchChannels());

ReactDOM.render(
    // But here, you're recreating the store again, which I think will re-initialise an empty store
    // Change this to use the `store` variable from above.
    <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: good spotting... I missed this and was getting ready to set up a jsfiddle to try to work this out.

Comment: That's it...  You know, wearing trifocals, you'd think my "eight eyes" would have seen this, but no....   In the end, I figured it would be something silly. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome. I couldn't see anything wrong with what you'd written either until I spotted this. :)